# Change Background of Single Page (ie Component) in Ionic 6 Vue 4.5.2 :

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

Using Ionic 6.17 / Vue 4.5.12

Goal...I want the Home page to have a unique background color, different from the remaining SPA (ie #000000 during testing...)

Setup...Single Page (Ionic/Vue) App....Using a 'base-layout' component as the app skeleton.  Home.vue utilizes the default slot in 'base-layout'

Problem...**Scoped styling in Home.vue does not work**.  As expected, un-scoped styling globally changes the background color  for every page, but is undesired (see 5 Attempts in sample code below...they ALL change the ion-content background color ONLY if the 'scope' attribute is not used, and thus are globally applied)

QUESTION... **Is there a way to use 'style scoped' in Home.vue to selectively change the background of the ion-content for Home.vue ONLY??**

```
BaseLayout.vue  
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
       ..various buttons
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <!-- DEFAULT SLOT for content -->
    <ion-content class="customStyles" fullscreen id="main-content">
      <slot></slot>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

    Home.vue
<template>
  <base-layout>
   <!-- some ionic components for content -->
  </base-layout>
</template>

<style scoped>
/*Attempt 1*/
ion-content {
    --background:#000000;
}
/*Attempt 2*/
ion-content {
    --ion-background-color:#000000;
}
/*Attempt 3*/
ion-content.customStyles {
  --background:#000000;
  background: #000000;
}
/*Attempt 4*/
:host {
    background: #000000;
}
/*Attempt 5*/
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
 
  ion-content {
    --ion-background-color: #000000;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would probably be to just pass the background-color as prop to your BaseLayout component like this:

BaseLayout.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
    <ion-header translucent>
      <ion-toolbar>
       ..various buttons
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>

    <!-- DEFAULT SLOT for content -->
    <ion-content 
      class="customStyles" 
      fullscreen 
      id="main-content"
      :style="`--ion-background-color: ${backgroundColor}`"
    >
      <slot></slot>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    backgroundColor: {
      type: String,
      default: 'white'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This way you can easily override the background color, by passing the value to the component:

```
<base-layout
  background-color="#000000"  
>
   <!-- some ionic components for content -->
</base-layout>
```

Comment: Great idea... although I have not encountered the syntax '${propName}' using the dollar-sign-curley-braces in a template.   Is this to reference the prop using object destructuring (as opposed to a simple string notation)?

Comment: That's the template literals feature which got introduced with ES6 (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).
It's basically the same as `'--ion-background-color: ' + backgroundColor`

Comment: Template literals...got it !   

Your suggestion even worked when passing CSS vars, very helpful to keep consistent with Theming classes....

props: {
      customBackgroundColor: {
        type: String,
        default: 'var(--ion-color-primary)'
      },

Comment: Yeah, it really helps to keep theming clean. Otherwise it gets messy really quick. Feel free to mark the answer as solved, if is working for you :)

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward solution is to just supply the background-color argument to your BaseLayout component.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.